# Removing fonts from fontconfig <match> results

Tags: firefox, fontconfig

I'd like to remove a few fonts from the fontconfig match results for firefox.

I know there's `<rejectfont>`, but it removes the font completely and for everyone, like it doesn't exist in the system.

I've tried to `prepend_first`, but turns out firefox has its own font-selecting algorithm that gets all the matches from fontconfig and reorder them (seems like it prefers scalable fonts if it can't find an exact size match from a bitmap font, unlike `fontconfig` itself that has a more complex and configurable font-matching logic), so the unwanted fonts should be left out of the list altogether.

`delete` and `delete_all` edit modes don't seem to work for that matter.

Is there a way to handle this better than patching firefox itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FONTCONFIG_FILE` or `FONTCONFIG_PATH` environment variables to change to fontconfig settings only for a process and its descendants:

```
$ cp /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /path/to/fonts-for-firefox.conf

# modify /path/to/fonts-for-firefox.conf as you see fit
# don't forget to change the include ..>conf.d< to >/etc/fonts/conf.d<

$ FONTCONFIG_FILE=/path/to/fonts-for-firefox.conf firefox ...
```