# Rejectfont problem

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

In `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` there is a rule excluding fonts from loading with firefox but given .fonts folder is blacklisted not only for firefox but for all others applications. Is there a way to blacklist some fonts only for specified application eg. firefox ?

```
<match>
    <test name="prgname">
        <string>firefox</string>
    </test>
        <selectfont>
            <rejectfont>
                <glob>/home/someuser/.fonts/*</glob>
            </rejectfont>
        </selectfont>
</match>
```

Seems like **prgname** is ignored. The same happened when rejecting specified font `<string>` instead of `<glob>`. Why is that ?

---

fontconfig: 2.13.1-4.4
fontconfig-config: 2.13.1-4.4
DE: Gnome 42

Comment: I don't think `selectfont` works like you want it to, it's a top-level element. You might want to do with a separate conf file for firefox.

Comment: @catemperor can you give an example of config ?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467903/removing-fonts-from-fontconfig-match-results